# How to write Azure Cosmos COUNT DISTINCT query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, distinct, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Goal**:

To return the count of distinct values of a particular document field within a partition of a Cosmos collection.

**Steps**:

If I run the following query on my Azure Cosmos database,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.field
FROM c
WHERE c.field = 'abc' AND c.partitionKeyField = '123'
```

I get one row as expected, e.g. the following response

```
[
    {
        "field": "abc"
    }
]
```

However, if I then run the following query in an attempt to count the number of distinct documents in the response, via the following query

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.field
    FROM c
    WHERE c.field = 'abc' AND c.partitionKeyField = '123'
)
```

It returns

```
[
    6
]
```

This is the total number of documents with `c.field` set to `"abc"` rather than the number of distinct values of `c.field`.

**Question**:

Please could you help me understand why the query returns the number of documents rather the number of distinct values for `c.field`, and if there is a query which will return the number of distinct values of `c.field`, i.e. 1?

Edit - PS. I know this a contrived example as by definition the number of unique values of `c.field` is always 1 - I have deliberately simplified this from the real case.

Comment: Interestingly `GROUP BY` returns what I'd like, e.g.

```sql
SELECT d.field, COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.field
    FROM c
    WHERE c.field = 'abc' AND c.partitionKeyField = '123'
) AS d
GROUP BY d.field
```

Returns 

```json
[
    {
        "field": "abc",
        "$1": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: This type of query is not reliable in my experience. I reported something similar [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38610298-bug-incorrect-results-returned-from-count-distinc) and got a ludicrous response that totally missed the point but raised it again through other channels and think it is on the radar to be fixed at some point...

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I should avoid using this query. Your link was one of the few pages I found with someone with a similar issue. Did you solve it with a `GROUP BY` like in the comment above, or something else?

Comment: I think I just concluded that I was out of luck trying to run this on CosmosDb and didn't come up with any workaround. Hopefully the `group by` works for you!

Answer (score 4):

At the moment of writing this (22/01/2021) this query provides correct number of distinct values:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(UniqueFields) AS UniqueCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.field
    FROM c
    WHERE c.field = 'abc' AND c.partitionKeyField = '123') as UniqueFields
```